# couchbase kafka connector connection error: illegal reflective access operation

Tags: java, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

My project needs to capture changes to an old version of CouchBase (v4.5). To address compatibility issues, an old version of the kafka couchbase connector (v3.1.2) is registered to kafka connect that is launched using strimzi kafka operator (v0.32). All related settings are correct, including connection cluster address, username, password and bucket. The connector is able to connect to the couchbase server. However, the connector fails to start due to the following error. Does anyone happen to know this issue and how to fix it?

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1 (file:/opt/kafka/plugins/couchbase-connector/28a854e7/kafka-connect-couchbase-3.1.2/share/java/kafka-connect-couchbase/core-io-1.4.2.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2022-12-02 04:14:07,256 ERROR [my-couchbase-connector|worker] WorkerConnector{id=my-couchbase-connector} Error while starting connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector) [connector-thread-my-couchbase-connector]
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot fetch configuration for bucket my_bucket
    at com.couchbase.connect.kafka.CouchbaseSourceConnector.start(CouchbaseSourceConnector.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doStart(WorkerConnector.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.start(WorkerConnector.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:346)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

It seems that problem is caused by the low version of the core-io package (core-io-1.4.2.jar) that is part of the [couchbase connector](

```
http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/kafka/3.1.2/kafka-connect-couchbase-3.1.2.zip
```

) (v3.1.2) used. However, it's not clear if this is the root cause of the problem. Simply creating a new zip file by replacing the core-io package with a newer version may cause other compatibility issues.

Comment: Not sure how are you getting the log. But I don't think the `ilegal access` is your issue. Your issue is `Cannot fetch configuration for bucket my_bucket` ... that seems like some issue with the connector configuration.

Comment: The `illegal reflective access` warnings suggest the connector will not work with the next Strimzi version based on Java 17. But in Strimzi 0.32 with Java 11, it is just a warning.

Comment: @Jakub You are right in that perhaps the `illegal reflective access` warning is not the issue. I unregistered the connector and re-registered it. Now that warning no longer showed up and I only saw the `Cannot fetch configuration for bucket` exception/

Comment: cross-reference: discussion in Couchbase forum https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-kafka-connector-connection-error-cannot-fetch-configuration-for-bucket/35047

Comment: Problem solved https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-kafka-connector-connection-error-cannot-fetch-configuration-for-bucket/35047/8